# SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)

Tags: ssl, gitlab

We have a gitlab server running on Debian, GitLab 7.1.0.

The SSL certificate expired and a new one was configured and added, yesterday.

Now users are reporting errors when they push to the server.

Thought it might a client side error, maybe an expired or duplicate certificate.
But the same error on occurs. All clients a Macs running OS X 10.10.5

Running Ruby: ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]

Below is the error:

```
git-tester:gifs_of_disapproval_ droga5_$ git push

Counting objects: 3, done.

Delta compression using up to 4 threads.

Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.

Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 258 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.

Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)

remote: /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)

remote:     from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `block in connect'

remote:     from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:54:in `timeout'

remote:     from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'

remote:     from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `connect'

remote:     from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:755:in `do_start'

remote:     from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:744:in `start'

remote:     from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_net.rb:76:in `get'

remote:     from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_net.rb:31:in `allowed?'

remote:     from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_update.rb:39:in `exec'

remote:     from hooks/update:13:in `'

remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master

To https://git.d5servers.com/athenos/gifs_of_disapproval_.git

 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (hook declined)

error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.d5servers.com/athenos/gifs_of_disapproval_.git'
```

I've tried force it to use http:

git config --global http.sslVerify false

But the error persists.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Mitch